# Polynomial Regression plot not showing correctly

Tags: python, regression

I run this code for polynomial regression using `sklearn` but my plot is not what i was expecting. As you can see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7UMr1.jpg) i'm not getting a smooth line but it's jumping from one point to another. From my understanding i have to sort X, but when i do that all i get is an empty plot with a linear line.

```
import operator
import numpy as np
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline
from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error, r2_score
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf

df = pd.read_csv('D:\Mall_Customers.csv', usecols = ['Age', 'Annual Income (k$)','Spending Score (1-100)'])


x = StandardScaler().fit_transform(df)


kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=3, max_iter=100)
y_kmeans= kmeans.fit_predict(x)

mydict = {i: np.where(kmeans.labels_ == i)[0] for i in range(kmeans.n_clusters)}

dictlist = []
for key, value in mydict.items():
    temp = [key,value]
    dictlist.append(temp)

df0 = df[df.index.isin(mydict[0].tolist())]
X = df0[['Age', 'Annual Income (k$)']]
Y = df0['Spending Score (1-100)']




poly_reg = PolynomialFeatures(degree=2)
X_poly = poly_reg.fit_transform(X)

model = LinearRegression()
model.fit(X_poly, Y)
y_poly_pred = model.predict(X_poly)


r2 = r2_score(Y,y_poly_pred)
print(r2)
model = make_pipeline(PolynomialFeatures(degree=2), LinearRegression(fit_intercept = False))
model.fit(X,Y)


plt.scatter(X.iloc[:, 1], Y, color='red')

plt.plot(X, Y, color='blue')
plt.xlabel('Age. Annual income')
plt.ylabel('Spending Score')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TLDR; the data is not linear dependent.

The reason the graph got so messy is because you plotted the `X` (train data) with the `Y` (the **actual** prediction data) and the fact that you were plotting this data while:

the **data was messy and not really linear dependent**
is what made the result this messy graph.

I suggest you to:

1. split to the train data into train, test and then after you train the model check the error with the test and maybe create 2 plots, 1 with the model results according to the test data and one with the actual result for the test data.
2. and change plot code to this:

.

```
plt.scatter(X, Y)
plt.plot(X, Y_pred, color='red')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Not sure if it would make a difference but, in my csv file i have the variable ```Gender``` that i haven't included in my code. Would including it solve my problem or should i do waht you suggested?

Comment: I don't think that matters to the fact that the plot didn't provide you a clear line.